# Expected value is defined in terms of probability measure or cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

[Expected value (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_case) is defined as follows:

> In general, if $X$ is a random variable defined on a probability space $(\Omega ,\Sigma ,\operatorname {P} )$, then the expected value of $X$, denoted by $\operatorname {E} [X]$, is defined as the Lebesgue integral
> $$\operatorname {E} [X]=\int _{\Omega }X(\omega )\,d\operatorname {P} (\omega ).$$
> Note that the integral is with respect to the probability measure.

However, [characteristic function (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Definition) seems to define expected value in a different way.

> $$\operatorname {E} \left[e^{itX}\right] = \int _{\mathbb {R} }e^{itx}\,dF_{X}(x)$$
> where $F_X$ is the cumulative distribution function of $X,$ and the integral is of the Riemann-Stieljes kind.

Based on the definition of expected value given in the characteristic function, we should have
$$\operatorname {E}(X) = \int _{\mathbb {R} }x\,dF_{X}(x).$$

I am wondering whether the two integrals above coincide, as the former is a Lebesgue integral (probability measure is the integrator) whereas the latter is a Riemann-Stieljes integral (CDF is the integrator).

Clearly measure and CDF are functions of different as their domains are different (one involves collection of sets, another involves element of set).

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mu_X(A)=P(X^{-1}(A))$. Then $\mu_X$ is a probability measure on the Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb R$ and the relation between $\mu_X$ and $F_X$ is given by $F_X(x)=\mu_X(-\infty,x]$. Now the defintion of $\mu_X$ gives $\int fd\mu =\int_{\Omega} f(X(\omega)) dP(\omega)$ because this holds when $f$ is an indicator function, hence when $f$ is  simple function, hence when $f$ is any non-negative measurable function or a function integrable w.r.t. $\mu_X$. Thus $\int e^{itX}dP=\int e^{itx} d\mu_X(x)=\int e^{itx} dF_X(x)$.
Note that the first integral here is over $\Omega$ and the other two are integrals over $\mathbb R$.